# How can I make this client as a multithread client?

Tags: java, networking

I have read a lot about multithread client but for this one,I can not make it multithread!
would you please help me?

```
public class MainClient implements Runnable{

private static InformationClass info = new InformationClass();
private static Socket c;
private static String text;

public static String getText() {
    return text;
}

public static void setText(String text) {
    MainClient.text = text;
}
private static PrintWriter os;
private static BufferedReader is;
static boolean closed = false;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {



    MainFrame farme = new MainFrame();
    farme.setVisible(true);
    try {
        c = new Socket("localhost", 5050);


        os = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream(), true);


        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void active() {

    String teXt = MainClient.getText();
    System.out.println(teXt);
    os.println(teXt);

    try {
        String line = is.readLine();
        System.out.println("Text received: " + line);
        os.flush();
        is.close();
        is.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      }
}
```

also active method will be called when the client write something on the text area and then clicks on the send button.

2) also i have a question that:

in the other class I have this action performed for my send button,does it mean that client is multithread??

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This gets run in a background thread
            String text = jTextArea1.getText();


            jTextArea2.append(client.getCurrentName() + " : " + text + "\n");
            MainClient.setText(client.getCurrentName() + " : " + text + "\n");
            clear();
            MainClient.active();

        }
    }).start();




}
```

Last EDIT:

this is my active method:

```
  public static void active() {

    String teXt = MainClient.getText();

    os.println(teXt);


        String line = is.readLine();
        System.out.println("Text received: " + line);
        os.flush();
        is.close();
        is.close();
        c.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer: YES. The code in the second snippet would create a new thread everytime the method jButton1ActionPerformed is called.

I am not sure if this is the intended behavior though.

Comment: So ,can I run 2 clients at the same time?

Comment: @Johanna, you probably need to specify the requirements more clearly to get a complete answer. What is it that you intend to do ?

Comment: i want make my program to run 2 or more clients at a time.I have learned that we should make our client class (which has socket in it)
implements runnable interface but I want to know that without doing this can we have such this actionperformed for the send button that do it for us?

Answer (score 0):

> does it mean that client is multithread??

Multithreading is the use of more than one thread. Technically yes you are multithreading.

> So ,can I run 2 clients at the same time?

Short answer, Yes.
Long answer, you will need to make sure your methods are thread-safe and the `MainCient` is not blocking or being blocked by any other thread.

When Multithreading, i usually tend to make a centralized class to control the "pool" of Threads. I call it the Dispatcher. Which manages a map of threads.

Comment: I have edited my post and I added my active method,really i don't know what you mean by "you will need to make sure your methods are thread-safe and the MainCient is not blocking or being blocked by any other thread." would you please help me that this active method is thread_safe?

Comment: I think you mean that make my active method as a synchronized one.yes?

Comment: If you have time read this: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/threadsafety.html, sync method is one implementation but not a magic stick.